# HTML5 video player won't load .vtt subtitle track

Tags: html5-video, closed-captions, vtt

I'm trying to add a subtitle track to a video and I can't figure out why it isn't working correctly.  Here is my HTML:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="../assets/video/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <track
    src="../assets/video/sample.vtt"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="en"
    label="English"
  />
</video>
```

And here is my .vtt file:

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.500 --> 00:00:02.000
The Web is always changing

00:00:02.500 --> 00:00:04.300
and the way we access it is changing
```

**Problem:**
When I run my website locally the video will load, but when I click on the closed captions button and select English, there is a console error that reads:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/video/sample.vtt 404 (Not Found).
```

If I deploy the website and run it from the server instead, selecting the English subtitle track doesn't display any errors, but...

- The subtitles don't appear on the video.
- The Closed Captions button is removed from the video player controls on Chrome.
- In other browsers, the Closed Caption button remains, but everything else is identical.

If I check the Network tab in Chrome dev tools, I can see that the request was made for `sample.vtt` at the correct request URL and returned a 200 status code.

The odd thing is that when I look at the response for that request, instead of seeing the text of the `.vtt` file, it shows the full text of my website's `index.html` file, which is located in an entirely separate folder.

I'm not sure why this is happening, and it seems like this should be a relatively simple thing to set up, so I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with Webpack.  This app is in Vue, so I added the following options under the "vue" rule in `vue.config.js`, and it worked:

```
config.module
      .rule("vue")
      .use("vue-loader")
      .loader("vue-loader")
      .tap((options) => {
        options.transpileOptions = {
          transforms: {
            dangerousTaggedTemplateString: true,
          },
        };
        options["transformAssetUrls"] = {
          video: ["src", "poster"],
          source: "src",
          img: "src",
          image: ["xlink:href", "href"],
          use: ["xlink:href", "href"],
          "b-embed": ["src", "poster"],
          track: "src",
        };
        return options;
      });
    config.module
      .rule("media")
      .test(/\.(vtt|mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/);
```